# Failed to create project in Eclipse plugin "Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse"

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Anyone faced this error in the Eclipse plugin "Project is not enabled for Cloud Dataflow".  I am trying to create a new dataflow project, provided "Account" & "Cloud Platform Project ID" and it tries to validate for a few secs by stating "Verifying that project is enabled for dataflow...". After that, it shows the above error.

[image]

I have gone through https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart-dataflow  and tried Point #3, but no luck. Am I missing something?

Comment: When you say you've gone through the quickstart, do you mean the entire quickstart? Are there any other steps that fail and what messages do they fail with? This might help narrow down the cause of the error. The section "Configure execution options" seems particularly relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I've followed the [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart-dataflow) you shared, and it works with a clean setup of Eclipse on Windows 10.

I'll point out the key elements that you must be aware in two parts.

First for the setup:

1. [Enable your billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#view_the_billing_account_linked_to_a_project). Select your project and go to the Billing section.
2. [Enable the APIs](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart-dataflow#before-you-begin) required you can do this by clicking the button of "Enable the APIS" in the third point. You'll have to select your project and once your APIs are enabled you'll receive a confirmation message.
3. Install the Java JDK version 1.8 or later.
4. Install [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/), version 4.7 or later
5. Install the [plugin](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart). In Help > Eclipse Marketplace... and search for Google Cloud. (You'll have to restart Eclipse after the
   installation)

At restart Eclipse will Install a couple of more libraries, so give it a few minutes to finish... A pop up message appears telling you this.

To create a DataFlow project, follow carefully the creation guide in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart-dataflow#create-a-dataflow-project-in-eclipse). If you mirror the configuration for testing it works.

1. Sing in your account.
2. Select the project ID where you enabled the APIs.
3. Select or create the bucket you are going to use. I created the bucket before creating the project from the Web Console.
4. You need a Service account key in a json file. You need a Service account key in json format. To create one go to the IAM & admin section, and under Service Accounts create one and download the key in a json file.

Once done this you click create, and that's it for the creation of the project.